# How to adjust player movement around a circumference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

Good Sunday Football afternoon everyone,
My issue is that I have a player controller in Unity that I am creating and the player is supposed to move left or right in a circular motion. Well I have created that but I'm having difficulties locating how to make the player move around a fixed circumference that will eventually be changed.
Here's what I got so far, and the code works. C#, unity, using a sphere.

```
//editable property
float timeCounter = 0;
public float speed;

void Start()
{
    //Called at the start of the game
    speed = 1;
}

void Update()
{
    timeCounter += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed; // multiply all this with some speed variable (* speed);
    float x = Mathf.Cos(timeCounter) ;
    float y = Mathf.Sin(timeCounter) + 6;
    float z = 0;
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Called before preforming physics calculations
}
```

}

Comment: So the player already is moving in a very small circle around (y=6) and I'm trying to get the circle to be a variable that can be changed as the level progresses the circumference can be manipulated to increase the movement range of the player.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the player moving at constant linear speed (and that I understood what you want), I would do something like that:

```
float playerAngle = 0;  // the angular position of the player
float playerSpeed = 0.5;  // the linear speed of the player
float radius = 1;  // the radius of the circle

void Update()
{
    playerAngle += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speed / radius;
    float x = radius * Mathf.Cos( playerAngle ) ;
    float y = radius * Mathf.Sin( playerAngle ) + 6;
    float z = 0;
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: @Sage.VS : yes.

Comment: So using your code i'm getting a really nasty error when doing the actual movement. The player object will no longer go in a full circle, but instead will do only part of an arc.

Comment: That's really strange, because for `radius = 1`, this code should be the same as yours...

Comment: It was all my fault, I'm running the new one again, Ill let you know. I just found my error with where I declared the variables

Comment: completely my fault

Comment: So One more thing. If I want to expand the rotation to say a larger circumference. How would you do that?

Comment: @Sage.VS : just set the `radius` variable to whatever value you want. You could even increase it slowly over time